# Statistics how to calculate likelihood over several draws

Tags: probability, statistics

I am working on a spreadsheet and am lousy at statistics. I am working on what is essentially a lottery to draw a winning number

I have a likelihood of drawing a win in percent, and number of attempts. What would I do to calculate it across $x$ number of tries?

I did number of tries * percent and I got numbers that seemed right. I wanted to make sure I was correct

Comment: What have you tried? Are you sampling with or without replacement? Does the probability of winning in a particular attempt change as you make more attempts?

Comment: What’s replacement? It’s like a basic lottery each contestant gets a number if the number is drawn they win. Odds do not change as more attempts are made

Comment: OK, but what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I did number of tries * percent and I got numbers that seemed right I wanted to make sure I was correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the probability of winning in one attempt is $p$.

Across $n$ attempts, the probability that you lose in all $n$ is $(1-p)^n$, assuming that each attempt is independent. So the probability that you win at least once is $\boxed{1-(1-p)^n}$.

When $p$ is very small, and so $np\ll1$, we have by the binomial approximation
$$1-(1-p)^n\approx1-(1-np)=np,$$
so your formula of number of tries x winning probability is a decent approximation.

Comment: Works for me I’ll accept it when I can thanks so much and for forgiving my lack of mathematical vocabulary !!!